# Why we can not add erc721 tokens in wallet?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, erc-721

I have created an erc721 token and when i try to transfer it from one address to another address that transaction is not visible on etherscan, moreover tokens are also not visible in mew or metamask? And on etherscan contract appear as erc20 contract not as erc721 contract.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "transaction is not visible on etherscan". How do you invoke it? ERC721 has ERC20 compatible functions, so appearence on etherscan is partially correct. But still, can you provide link to your contract?

Comment: OP means that it does not show up as an owned token on etherscan.

Answer (score 4):

Etherscan, MetaMask and other wallets do not currently support the ERC-721 standard.

The actual standard was just passed last week.

We are hosting a conference this weekend in Dallas to discuss interoperability details for Dapps and wallets. MetaMask is a sponsor for the conference. I'm probably not supposed to say this, but you could infer from this that MetaMask is going to support 721 in the future.